# when using contractions.fix on the dataframe in pandas shows IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk

I am trying to use `contractions.fix` to expand the words in my dataset. But when I run the code and try to add the expanded words to a new column in the dataset, I get an error String index out of range. I tried to search everywhere possible about it but I could not find a solution.

Screenshot of the Dataset, I want to run `contractions.fix` on `comments` column

[image: img]

The screenshot of the code and the error is thrown:

[image: This is the code I am using and it shows the error(below in the screenshot)]

This is my code to run contractions.fix:

```py
rws["expanded_words"]=rws['comments'].apply(lambda x: [contractions.fix(word) for word in x.split()])
```

Comment: Similar code worked for me. Did you figure out what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked as soon as I had these NLTK extensions downloaded via the following code:

```py
nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('onw-1.4')
nltk.download('averaged_percepton_tagger')
```